# Angular - How do I wait for a function from a service to complete before assigning variable value

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass the result of a function from my service to a component. However the issue I am having is that the service function is executing after the page loads, therefore the variable I'm assigning is undefined at that point.

If I add a time out it works, but was looking for a better solution, as I don't think that's the correct approach.

I have been trying to use an observable but lacking knowledge to get it working, so would appreciate any help.

This is the function in the service:

```js
  load_documents() {
   
    this.apiPost = {
            "credentials":
              {"user_name":localStorage.username,"password":localStorage.password,"application":settings.application,"eEncryption_type":settings.encryption_type},
            "criteria":
              {"date_from":"2021-06-19T07:00:00.000Z","date_to":"2022-07-20T06:59:00.000Z","publish":1}
          }

   this.apiService.getDocuments(this.apiPost).subscribe((apiResponse: any)  => {
 
   this.jsonobj = JSON.parse(apiResponse.d);
 
var documents= [];

for (var i in this.jsonobj.rows) {

documents.push({
 doc_id: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[0].paragraphs[0].value,
 icon: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[1].paragraphs[0].value,
 title: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[2].paragraphs[0].value,
 date: moment(this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[3].paragraphs[0].value).format('LLL'),
 publication: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[4].paragraphs[0].value,
 stage: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[5].paragraphs[0].value,
 author: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[6].paragraphs[0].value,
 checked_out: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[7].paragraphs[0].value,
 entity: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[8].paragraphs[0].value,
 completed: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[9].paragraphs[0].value,
 bus_area: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[10].paragraphs[0].value,
 language: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[11].paragraphs[0].value,
 filename: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[12].paragraphs[0].value,
 distribution_status: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[13].paragraphs[0].value,
 summary_text: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[14].paragraphs[0].value,
 selected:   true,
 price: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[15].paragraphs[0].value,  
 clientType: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[19].paragraphs[0].value,
 favourites: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[23].paragraphs[0].value, 
 subtitle: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[25].paragraphs[0].value,
 docprice: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[27].paragraphs[0].value,
 doctp: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[28].paragraphs[0].value,
 docrec: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[29].paragraphs[0].value,  
 migrated: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[30].paragraphs[0].value,
 analystsList: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[31].paragraphs[0].value,
 classificationsList: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[32].paragraphs[0].value, 
 favourite_main: this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[23].paragraphs[0].value,
}
)

if(this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[25].paragraphs[0].value !== '' ){
  this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[25].paragraphs[0].value = '- '
}
else{
this.jsonobj.rows[i].cells[25].paragraphs[0].value = ' '
}
}
this.alertify.success('Documents loaded');
DocumentService.documents = documents ;

   }, error => {
     this.alertify.error(error);
   });
 }
```

And this is the call in the component (works if I put a timeout):

```js
load_documents() {

  this.documentService.load_documents();
    setTimeout (() => {
      this.documents = DocumentService.documents;
      }, 1500);
  }
```

Doesn't work if I remove the timeout:

```js
load_documents() {

  this.documentService.load_documents();
  this.documents = DocumentService.documents;
 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subscribe in component:

```js
load_documents() {
  //
  return this.apiService.getDocuments(this.apiPost);
}

load_documents() {
  this.documentService.load_documents().subscribe((apiResponse) => {
    //
  });
}
```